# Include value in array if condition is true

Tags: ruby

What's the idiomatic Ruby way of including a value in an array only if a condition is true?

```
class ItemPolicy
    def initialize(user)
        @user = user
        @allowed = user.manager?
    end

    # Suggest improvements to the permitted_attributes method
    def permitted_attributes
        [:name, :details] + (@allowed ? [:price] : [])
    end
end
```

This doesn't feel very Ruby-ish.

Comment: I think that's perfectly fine

Comment: I don't like the fact that I have to put the single element to be added in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
def permitted_attributes
  Array[
    :name,
    :details,
    *@allowed ? :price : nil
  ]
end
```

or on one line if you prefer:

```
def permitted_attributes
  [:name, :details, *@allowed ? :price : nil]
end
```

Comment: Anyone care to explain the downvotes?  This is perfectly valid and correct.

Comment: I actually like it. Add parentheses before the splat to make it more obvious. [:name, :details, *(@allowed ? :price : nil)]

Comment: @monkbroc I don't care for unnecessary parens because they are a distraction to anyone who knows their operator precedence. The splat operator is SUPER low in terms of precedence--even lower than `?:`. I would prefer using the multi-line equivalent over adding superfluous parens.

Comment: That's a matter of preference I suppose. In this case I find it kills two birds with one stone: visually groups the ternary operator and makes it clear that the splat applies to the result of the ternary, not the boolean attribute.

Comment: @monkbroc Different strokes, friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with it, but I have a feeling that method might grow over time and get a bit more confusing.  I'm not sure why `@allowed` is outside the method, but ignoring that I'd probably do this:

```
def permitted_attributes
  permitted = [:name, :details]
  permitted += :price if @allowed
  permitted
end
```

That way you can grow it over time and add other logic, while keeping it readable.

Comment: Unless this is in a rails controller I'd recommend passing that in as an argument then.  At least consider it.

Comment: This way seems more like you would write it in C++. Ruby tends to have a more functional style using `collect` and such.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do something like this...

```
@allowed = false
def permitted_attributes
  [
    :name,
    :details,
    *(:price if @allowed),
  ]
end
```

Honestly that's kind of confusing in my opinion though. Really the best way is probably to just keep it simple:

```
def permitted_attributes
  attrs = [:name, :details]
  attrs << :price if @allowed
  attrs
end
```

Comment: @IronSavior If I remove the last line, `permitted_attributes` will be `nil` when `@allowed` is false.

Comment: quite right... nevermind.  I need to go eat lunch or something, I'm getting stupid.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def add_object_if(object_to_add)
    if yield
      self << object_to_add
    else
      self
    end
  end
end

arr = [1,2]
bool = true
arr.add_object_if(3) { bool }
p arr #=> [1, 2, 3]
bool = false
arr.add_object_if(4) { bool }
p arr #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: why including that in the Array class?  seems like nuclear-level overkill

Comment: If this is a nuclear-level overkill, then Rails should have destroyed the world by now.

Comment: Can't disagree there, but I'm not one for atomic war.  Why not put this method in application_controller (presuming this snippet is from a controller) if it's applicable across more than one file?  If not, then just make it a method for *this* controller.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I could could think of was maybe wrapping the conditional into a small method of its own, which provides a clearer context of why.

Also thought I'd add a `attr_reader` to remove the reuse of the instance variable.

```
class ItemPolicy
  attr_reader :allowed

  def initialize(user)
      @user = user
      @allowed = user.manager?
  end

  # Suggest improvements to the permitted_attributes method
  def permitted_attributes
    [:name, :details] + conditional_attributes
  end

  def conditional_attributes
    return [] unless allowed
    [:price]
  end
end
```